# Controlling Healthcheck with a Compose file in DDEV-Local

Tags: docker-compose, ddev

Using DDEV Local a project will sometimes fail the healthcheck, but then eventually become available. How could someone disable the healthcheck in order to better diagnose what is happening in a container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the integration of docker-composer we can create a compose file for healthcheck and adjust its settings as needed.

To start add a `docker-compose.healthcheck.yaml` file to your `.ddev` directory.

Then to disable the healthcheck it should look something like this:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD','true'] //disable the healthcheck
```

In this example we use `['CMD','true']` to force the test to pass, rather than using `disable:true`, because the disable key cannot be paired with other options which are set by default.

Additionally, if you would like to adjust the `timeout` before a container fails you can  adjust the compose file like so:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    healthcheck:
      timeout: 30s //set how long before healthcheck fails
```

You can also familiarize yourself more with the available options for healthcheck via the [Compose File Healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#healthcheck) docs.

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1

To disable Docker healthcheck you can use `test: ["NONE"]`.

```yaml
services:
  your-service:
    healthcheck:
      test: ["NONE"]
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#healthcheck

I use docker-compose version 1.25.0 and Docker Compose Document version '3.1'.

It doesn't work for me, but it is described in the documentation.

```yaml
healthcheck:
  disable: true
```

### Option 2

But, I don't know a reason, a part of `docker-compose.override.yml` don't work with that settings. Parents `docker-compose.yml` have health settings, I think it makes the error.

```
ERROR: Service "nginx" defines an invalid healthcheck: "disable: true" cannot be combined with other options
```

To disable it in `docker-compose.override.yml` I use the following settings:

```yaml
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "none"]
```

### Option 3

I think another way to disable healthcheck is using different docker-compose configs:

- the base `docker-compose.yml` without healthcheck.
- the second `docker-compose.healthcheck.yml` with healthcheck that will be combined with the parent `docker-compose.yml`:

```sh
# With healthcheck
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.healthcheck.yml up

# With override
docker-compose up

# Without override and healthcheck
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
```